# Installing Python package will download, install, and remove other packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cvxopt

I want to install `cvxopt` in Anaconda Python. Here's the version of my software:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
$ conda --version
conda 4.5.11
$ anaconda --version
anaconda Command line client (version 1.6.14)
```

I try to install by typing:

```
conda install cvxopt
```

I was prompted that about 40 packages will be downloaded, about 10 NEW packages will be installed, the package `anaconda` will be removed, and about 25 packages will be updated?

1. Are the NEW packages dependencies?
2. Why will conda remove the `anaconda` package? Isn't conda a part of anaconda?

Here is the full output:

```
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /usr/local/anaconda3

  added / updated specs: 
    - cvxopt


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    suitesparse-5.2.0          |       h171a5a3_0         2.4 MB
    openssl-1.1.1a             |       h7b6447c_0         5.0 MB
    freetype-2.9.1             |       h8a8886c_1         822 KB
    harfbuzz-1.8.8             |       hffaf4a1_0         863 KB
    libssh2-1.8.0              |       h1ba5d50_4         233 KB
    cairo-1.14.12              |       h8948797_3         1.3 MB
    libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0         |       hdf63c60_1         2.9 MB
    conda-4.6.1                |           py36_0         1.7 MB
    glpk-4.65                  |       h3ceedfd_2         1.1 MB
    expat-2.2.6                |       he6710b0_0         187 KB
    krb5-1.16.1                |       h173b8e3_7         1.4 MB
    tbb-2018.0.5               |       h6bb024c_0         1.4 MB
    sqlite-3.26.0              |       h7b6447c_0         1.9 MB
    cvxopt-1.2.0               |   py36h9e0dedd_0         537 KB
    glib-2.56.2                |       hd408876_0         5.0 MB
    python-3.6.8               |       h0371630_0        34.4 MB
    certifi-2018.11.29         |           py36_0         146 KB
    gsl-2.4                    |       h14c3975_4         2.6 MB
    cryptography-2.4.2         |   py36h1ba5d50_0         618 KB
    libuuid-1.0.3              |       h1bed415_2          16 KB
    curl-7.63.0                |    hbc83047_1000         145 KB
    libgcc-ng-8.2.0            |       hdf63c60_1         7.6 MB
    fribidi-1.0.5              |       h7b6447c_0         112 KB
    ca-certificates-2018.12.5  |                0         123 KB
    pango-1.42.3               |       h8589676_0         522 KB
    libpng-1.6.36              |       hbc83047_0         346 KB
    pycurl-7.43.0.2            |   py36h1ba5d50_0         185 KB
    tk-8.6.8                   |       hbc83047_0         3.1 MB
    qt-5.9.7                   |       h5867ecd_1        85.9 MB
    mkl-2018.0.3               |                1       198.7 MB
    libcurl-7.63.0             |    h20c2e04_1000         550 KB
    metis-5.1.0                |       hf484d3e_4         4.1 MB
    fontconfig-2.13.0          |       h9420a91_0         291 KB
    matplotlib-3.0.2           |   py36h5429711_0         6.5 MB
    pillow-5.4.1               |   py36h34e0f95_0         627 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       373.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cvxopt:          1.2.0-py36h9e0dedd_0   
    fribidi:         1.0.5-h7b6447c_0       
    glpk:            4.65-h3ceedfd_2        
    gsl:             2.4-h14c3975_4         
    krb5:            1.16.1-h173b8e3_7      
    libuuid:         1.0.3-h1bed415_2       
    metis:           5.1.0-hf484d3e_4       
    suitesparse:     5.2.0-h171a5a3_0       
    tbb:             2018.0.5-h6bb024c_0    

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    anaconda:        5.2.0-py36_3           

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0            --> 2018.12.5-0            
    cairo:           1.14.12-h7636065_2      --> 1.14.12-h8948797_3     
    certifi:         2018.4.16-py36_0        --> 2018.11.29-py36_0      
    conda:           4.5.11-py36_0           --> 4.6.1-py36_0           
    cryptography:    2.2.2-py36h14c3975_0    --> 2.4.2-py36h1ba5d50_0   
    curl:            7.60.0-h84994c4_0       --> 7.63.0-hbc83047_1000   
    expat:           2.2.5-he0dffb1_0        --> 2.2.6-he6710b0_0       
    fontconfig:      2.12.6-h49f89f6_0       --> 2.13.0-h9420a91_0      
    freetype:        2.8-hab7d2ae_1          --> 2.9.1-h8a8886c_1       
    glib:            2.56.1-h000015b_0       --> 2.56.2-hd408876_0      
    harfbuzz:        1.7.6-h5f0a787_1        --> 1.8.8-hffaf4a1_0       
    libcurl:         7.60.0-h1ad7b7a_0       --> 7.63.0-h20c2e04_1000   
    libgcc-ng:       7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        --> 8.2.0-hdf63c60_1       
    libpng:          1.6.34-hb9fc6fc_0       --> 1.6.36-hbc83047_0      
    libssh2:         1.8.0-h9cfc8f7_4        --> 1.8.0-h1ba5d50_4       
    libstdcxx-ng:    7.2.0-hdf63c60_3        --> 8.2.0-hdf63c60_1       
    matplotlib:      2.2.2-py36h0e671d2_1    --> 3.0.2-py36h5429711_0   
    mkl:             2018.0.2-1              --> 2018.0.3-1             
    openssl:         1.0.2o-h20670df_0       --> 1.1.1a-h7b6447c_0      
    pango:           1.41.0-hd475d92_0       --> 1.42.3-h8589676_0      
    pillow:          5.1.0-py36h3deb7b8_0    --> 5.4.1-py36h34e0f95_0   
    pycurl:          7.43.0.1-py36hb7f436b_0 --> 7.43.0.2-py36h1ba5d50_0
    python:          3.6.5-hc3d631a_2        --> 3.6.8-h0371630_0       
    qt:              5.9.5-h7e424d6_0        --> 5.9.7-h5867ecd_1       
    sqlite:          3.23.1-he433501_0       --> 3.26.0-h7b6447c_0      
    tk:              8.6.7-hc745277_3        --> 8.6.8-hbc83047_0       

Proceed ([y]/n)? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.
```

Comment: are you running the conda install after activating the virtual environment?

Comment: @d_kennetz Since it's the first time I hear of "virtual environment", my answer is probably no.

Comment: prior to running the install, do `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate`. You will see a little `(base)` in front of your username meaning you are installing inside a venv. Then, try `conda install cvxopt`. I have a good idea of what is going on, but if this does not fix your problem my idea is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `anaconda` package is called a "meta-package" because it does not contain any code itself, but instead specifies dependencies of other packages that should be installed. The package `cvoptx` is not one of the packages specified by the `anaconda` package, so if you try to install `cvoptx`, there is a conflict that conda resolves by removing the `anaconda` package (since you give `cvoptx` higher priority by specifying as required to be installed in the environment).

`conda` and `anaconda` are separate, and have separate versions. `conda` is the command line interface that allows you to install, update, and remove packages and environments. `anaconda` is described above.

Finally (and confusingly), the `anaconda` command on the command line is provided by the `anaconda-client` package, not the `anaconda` package. If you want to see the version of Anaconda that is installed, use `conda list anaconda`. If you want the version of the `anaconda-client` command line tool, use `anaconda --version`. The `anaconda-client` is used to upload packages and environments to https://anaconda.org

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to install it in a separate environment. It is recommended to have different environments for each project. I tend to avoid mixing project requirements together. For the project using cvxopt, I would do:

```
conda create --name cvx python=3.6
```

So here I create an environment called cvx that has Python 3.6

This will download all needed packages for Python36. Since it is a clean environment, there would be no upgrading or downgrading.

After that you can activate your environment as:

```
conda activate cvx

conda install -c conda-forge cvxopt
```

In these environment you have cvxopt. You can the build your project and run it in these environment. If you need extra packages, you can do:

```
conda install -n cvxopt PACKAGESNAME
```

Here is everything you need to know to work with environments https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html